# what to do when i get error: origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: database, http, browser, server

HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/8.5.96

to save the input of user in database